# Excel run-time error 91, without object variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm receiving a **`Run-time Error '91' Object Variable or With Block not Set`** for the following code.

I'm confused as I'm not using any object variables (I don't think, I'm new to VBA). Debugging highlights the 6th row.

My code is:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Find(What:="" & Cells(i, 19).Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
MsgBox ActiveCell.Row
```

Comment: your code looks okay to me, add `Option Explicit` on top also close the work book and reopen it see if that helps.

Comment: You're using lots of `object variables`; they're just not the ones you declare. `Columns`, `Selection`, and `ActiveCell` can all be not set in the code you've posted above. The debugger can tell you which aren't. There are dozens of existing questions here about this exact error, with answers that explain how to track them down and how to resolve the problem. Did you search on that exact error message via Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm receiving a Run-time Error '91' Object Variable or With Block not Set for the following code.

When working with `.Find`, check if a match was returned and then show the row if found else you will get the above error.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    i = 1

    '~~> Replace this with the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=.Cells(i, 19).Value, _
                                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                     MatchCase:=False, _
                                     SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> Check if the find returned a match
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox aCell.Row
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```